# How to make user permissions that expire after 24 hours?

Tags: django, django-models, permissions

I'm creating a service where I give users who pay for access - access for a timed period, i.e. 24 hours.

Once they've made a payment. I auto file data into this premium model:

```
class Premium(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    datetime_payment = model.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    has_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user']
        permissions = (("can_access_premium", "Premium Access"),)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}({self.has_premium})'
```

So I want the user permissions for premium access to end after 24 hours. How can I change a user permissions. They can buy multiple times, so the trigger for this 24-permission is a payment.

Comment: add some middleware that compares current datetime with their `dateimtime_payment`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try middleware something like this.  You will need to amend the date comparison for your purposes and write the code to change the user permissions.

```
class PremiumMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        user = request.user

        # if the user is not logged in..
        if user.is_anonymous():
            return response

        # ..or it is not active..
        if not user.datetime_payment > datetime.datetime.now():
            # do something here to change the user permissions
            return response
```